# Custom Entity: define a view in entity reference field

Tags: 8, forms, entities

I defined a custom entity and for a entity reference field I want to set the view reference widget and a view/ display to be used instead of an autocomplete.

I tried many different settings - nothing worked. The latest version not working is:

```
$fields['user'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('User account'))
  ->setDescription(t('The user account this profile is connected to'))
  ->setSetting('target_type','user')
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'label' => 'inline',
    'type' => 'string',
    'weight' => -6,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'views',
    'settings' => array(
      'handler_settings' => array(
        'view_name' => 'users_without_profile',
        'display_name' => 'entity_reference_1',
        'arguments' => []
      ),
      'weight' => 20
    )

  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

For the form view setting I also tried

```
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'views',
    'settings' => array(
      'view_name' => 'users_without_profile',
      'display_name' => 'entity_reference_1',
      'arguments' => [],
      'weight' => 20
    )
  ))
```

and

```
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
    'settings' => array(
        'handler' => 'views',
        'handler_settings' => array(
            'view_name' => 'users_without_profile',
            'display_name' => 'entity_reference_1',
            'arguments' => [],
        ),          
        'weight' => 20
    )
  ))
```

No success. Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: One way to find out: Add a field through the UI, configure it exactly as you want to, then pop to admin -> Configuration -> Config Synchronisation -> Export -> Single Item. You can export the field instance and/or storage into the text area to find out exactly how the settings array should be structured

Comment: I tried it that way - this is how I found these ideas. But I think I missed something

Comment: If you look at the export for a reference field you'll see a top level `settings` item - this has a `handler` and `handler_settings`, which are the ones you want to manipulate. I've added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the previous answer was missing a small detail: the information about the view needs to be wrapped into an array with key 'view' llike following:

```
$fields['user'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('User account'))
  ->setDescription(t('The user account this profile is connected to'))
  ->setSetting('target_type','user')
  ->setSetting('handler', 'views')
  ->setSetting('handler_settings', [
    'view' => [
      'view_name' => 'users_without_profile',
      'display_name' => 'entity_reference_1',
      'arguments' => [],
    ]
  ])
```

In this way it is finally working

Answer (score 1):

The handler settings are part of the base field itself, rather than being a setting for the form display.

This should work:

```
$fields['user'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('User account'))
  ->setDescription(t('The user account this profile is connected to'))
  ->setSetting('target_type','user')
  ->setSetting('handler', 'views')
  ->setSetting('handler_settings', [
    'view_name' => 'users_without_profile',
    'display_name' => 'entity_reference_1',
    'arguments' => [],
  ])
  ...
```